# i cant canfigure pgina for ldap login

Tags: configuration, openldap

hi this is mi ldap user tree:

```
dc=intranet,dc=internet,dc=com
    cn=admin
        cn=user1
        cn=bna
        ou=buo
             cn=user2
```

I want to log with anyone user in the tree and assign a special role to those in the group buo whit pgina for windows.

This is the configuration I am using:

```
Search DN: cn=admin,dc=intranet,dc=internet,dc=com
Group DN pattern:uid=%g,dc=intranet,dc=internet,dc=com   Member Attribute: memberUid

Search for dn:
search filter: uid=%u
search context:dc=intranet,dc=internet,dc=com
```

User login works but did not find the group or the relationship between user and group

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A group is something different from an ou.

A group is a single ldap entry with a multiple "member attribute" enumerating the members.

The ou is a container (like a subtree) containing zero or more (user) entries.

While ous and groups can be used to solve the same problems, they are different tools.

So you can't expect pGina translate ou members in group members.